# Floodlight tag in asp.net master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, tracking

I am planning to implement floodlight tag in my website. I know I need to place the floodlight tags after ***body*** tag. But they way my website is designed that all the aspx pages use one single master page. Since the master page is going to contain the ***body*** tag. How to add floodlight tags for each page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a Literal control after your body tag in the master page and set this in your aspx code behind i.e.,

In you master page...

```
...
</body>
<asp:Literal id="ltrFloodlightTag" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Then in an aspx.cs page where the masterpage is used...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....
    Literal ltrFloodlightTag = (Literal)Master.FindControl("ltrFloodlightTag");
    ltrFloodlightTag.Text = "<img src='http://flodlightstuff/info.aspx?this=123&that=321' width='1px' height='1px' />";
}
```

Similarly, you could just use an img in the masterpage and simply set the src attribute from the aspx (if there is going to be a floodlight on each page this might make more sense).

I think this is what you might be getting at and I've actually got the meaning of floodlight tags correct!